# Upload a Folder Exactly with PHP Ajax with Progress

Tags: php, ajax, html, upload, directory

I want to upload a complete folder as is onto the Web-Server using PHP.

We chose directory like:

```
         .\
          |-Hello.txt
          |-Filen.jpg
          |-anotherfile.png
          |-File with Spaces.ext
          |-Folder -\
                    |-A file in a Folder.txt
                    |-Anohter Folder in Folder
                               -\
                                |-A file.ext
```

Then it should be uploaded as :

```
   web-www/
          |-Hello.txt
          |-Filen.jpg
          |-anotherfile.png
          |-File with Spaces.ext
          |-Folder -/
                    |-A file in a Folder.txt
                    |-Anohter Folder in Folder
                               -/
                                |-A file.ext
```

That means it should **retain the folder order** as is while uploading to webserver.

I have tried using some PHP Script (one of then being [this](http://sapphion.com/2011/11/html5-folder-upload-with-webkitdirectory/)). But it upload all the files (be in the folder or another subfolder) in the same location. Having a Progress bar would be Good. Please Help me!!

Comment: As far as I know, any UA will never allow you to get information about the local file system using HTML5. It will possibly be doable using a java applet or maybe even in Flash.

Comment: What if we give the info like the File Choose menu ?? (also the script I have specified in the Script allows to Choose a Folder on a webkit based Browser)

Comment: No, AFAIK the browser's file info dialog is just a browser's help to pick one path. It is completely unaccessible by any script. And for good reason, think about privacy. If any web site could read my file structure like that, I would immediately stop using the internet. :) The demo of the script you linked to simply opened a dialog on my box.

Comment: Try using a Webkit Based Browser like Chrome, when you click the Choose File Button, it pops up a dialog, which allows you to choose a Folder/File, and about Privacy, this script can NOT access the files until we interact.

Comment: True. I overlooked the 'choose a folder' thing. Pretty nifty. But I still doubt if the javascript can still access the original folder structure, or that all it can see is nothing more than a list of files... Anyway, most useful scenario seems to be a solution that only works in webkit. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, at least here (for me), maybe other browsers may implement it anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible. I've been playing around with it for a while, building an ajax folder uploader for a little app I've been building.

I hate to say it, but I don't believe (As of yet) this is possible outside of webkit browsers.

But it can be achieved using webkitRelativePath.

http://sapphion.com/2012/06/keep-directory-structure-when-uploading/

Comment: As said in the example, I prepared a Script, but It did not work, maybe  I had done something wrong. Can you please give me a example Script for the same (to see what was my mistake or is it actually possible).

Comment: Can you share your current code? 
I'd be able to amend it or at least provide a more relevant example.

Comment: It seams like my PHP script part is missing something. I used the Same HTML and also included the Javascript for debug (console output) but again it uploaded all the files in the same location. Can you please give me a PHP script for upload (something else would be fine if not PHP) ?? I used this PHP as is the simplest `$target = "files/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['files']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Error!.";
 }`

Comment: I have amended the link I posted above to include working server-side code and AJAX upload. I've written the example in raw javascript as you didn't mention which (If any) js library you're using.
Currently, there's no progress bar, I'm afraid.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Good, better than what I got from others. This does work good, but anyhow it uploads no more than 18 files, I tested this on multiple servers thinking maybe a server fault (2 of 5 dint work, 1 of them dint gave any response, and 2 were localhost -uploaded just 18 files- testing with 2 different folders) but dint help. Also I found that it initiates XHR for all at once, that maybe a serious stability issue, it should run one after other. Also dont automate such kind of process, Keep a button to upload the files(stability). I modified it for that. I  love MooTools and JQuery. Need a fix for it.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure you cannot do that, even with html5.

Best solution is archiving the files and folders and manage them on server, but ajax cannot upload a folder.

Comment: Any thing other than Ajax, Like POST sending the data to PHP Script ?

Comment: Thanks @Mihai Iorga